# Do I need the /GS compiler switch in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, lnk2019, compiler-options

After migrating our software from VS2005 to VS2012 I get the following error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function _main
```

which is caused by using /GS option. In VS2012 there is an extended secure switch /sdl. Don't I need /GS any more? If no, how can I solve this problem without forgoing the security?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the reason was additional libraries, which were migrated from vs2005. Project compiles with both options now.

Comment: And what those additional libraries would be?